# TOAD "Credential retrieval failed" error

Tags: oracle, toad

Semi-regularly when using TOAD, I will try to connect to a DB and get the error "ORA-12638 Credential retrieval failed".  I have to restart my TOAD to get past this.  It's a pain if I have other connections active.  Does anyone know how to avoid or get around this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Go to /oracle home/network/admin and open sqlnet.ora

2) Search for  SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS) and change it to
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

Comment: But it arises another problem:after that you will not be able to connect to the database without username/password:

>sqlplus / as sysdba

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Do you have any idea?

P.S I want to fix "ORA-12638 Credential retrieval failed" and 
"ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" together not just one of them.